# change Text of a textView

Tags: android

I have an Android app with a button and a textview, so I have a working counter that count the times clicked on the button, and it shows by a toast, but y want to show te counter in the text view and I can't

```
 int contadorClicks = 0;//numero de veces clickado
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);// button
    final TextView veces = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2); // textview to show the time clicked of contadorClicks



    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //definir accion
            contadorClicks++;
            //mostrar por pantalla toast el numero de veces para comprobarlo
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(contadorClicks), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            veces.setText(contadorClicks);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Quick answer: `veces.setText("" + contadorClicks);` - This will convert the integer to a string.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
veces.setText(String.valueOf(contadorClicks));
```

Answer (score 1):

because you setting int value to textview which is considered as resource so you can replace as below

```
veces.setText(""+contadorClicks);
```